# Issues in some contents of Excel web access web part in mozila firefox and google chrom

Tags: 2013, web-part, excel, access

Whenever we create an Excel web page, using Excel web access web part, we got an option `"open in excel"`. That `"open in excel"` option is not working in google chrome but it is working in Internet Explorer.

In Mozilla Firefox no options inside Excel web page is working. Why is that?

Comment: what solution u r talikng about?

Answer (score 3):

Not a hundred percent sure about this particular webpart, but most times when this type of issues occur, it is because the functionality is dependent on some Active X components to interact with your computer. Only Internet Explorer can work with Active X.

For some functions, Microsoft have tried to find alternative solutions (that is probable the reason why some functionality do work in Chrome but not in Firefox).