# Excel Web Access Web Part in SharePoint Online not working

Tags: web-part, jquery, excel-web-access-webpart

I have added 3 Excel Web Access Web Part on page in SharePoint online.

I have display web part on tab click. 
I have used jquery show , hide .

Its working fine in chrome browser.

Please see the below image for chrome
[image: Chrome]

But It shows blank in Firefox browser like below

[image]

Comment: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/81096/issues-in-some-contents-of-excel-web-access-web-part-in-mozila-firefox-and-googl

Comment: If you are using SP Online, would you not be able to add the excels as iframes? Using OWA? If you are dependent on the hillbilly tabs, just use 3 script editor webparts to embed each frame.

Comment: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Embed-your-Excel-workbook-on-your-web-page-or-blog-from-SharePoint-or-OneDrive-for-Business-7af74ce6-e8a0-48ac-ba3b-a1dd627b7773?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1

Comment: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Share-it-Embed-an-Excel-workbook-on-your-web-page-or-blog-from-OneDrive-804e1845-5662-487e-9b38-f96307144081

Comment: The  links that you are provided not helping me here. 
I have added 3 webpart on page and write script in script editor like you said

Answer (score 0):

Do following steps:

1. Check, if JQuery is loaded correctly (F12 Developer Tools)
2. Try to show/hide it manually in F12 Developer Tools
3. Check also for errors in Console while Loading the Site

Could you try these steps and I'll try to update the answer

Comment: 1)Yes,JQuery is loaded correctly
2)Yes its working .show/hide it manually in F12 Developer Tools
3)No. There is no error in console